# Proper replacement for loop in MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[image]

And I want to find the level that appears most often for each age, for example for age 18 the level that appears most is "FR" and for age 19 it is "SO".

My try:

```
SELECT X.AGE, X.LEVEL FROM 
( SELECT S.AGE, S.LEVEL FROM STUDENT S WHERE S.AGE = 18) AS X 
GROUP BY X.LEVEL 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I get this result:

[image]

How to make iterate on all distinct ages which they are in this list `SELECT DISTINCT S.AGE FROM STUDENT S;` knowing that I'm prevented from using while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it if you `GROUP BY AGE, LEVEL` and use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AGE, 
       FIRST_VALUE(LEVEL) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) LEVEL 
FROM STUDENT  
GROUP BY AGE, LEVEL
```

or if you want ties returned use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT AGE, LEVEL,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AGE ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk 
  FROM STUDENT 
  GROUP BY AGE, LEVEL 
) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

These queries work for MySql 8.0+

Answer (score 1):

Before MySQL 8.0 you would have to use a self-join.

First you extract the ages and level, with counts.

```
SELECT AGE, LEVEL, COUNT(*) AS C FROM STUDENT GROUP BY AGE, LEVEL
```

This gets you, say,

```
18 FR 2
18 SR 5
18 XX 5
19 FR 1
```

From this, you select the maximum value for each one age - but you want only one row, and both SR and XX have a max with the same value of 5 when age is 18. Otherwise you could use a self-join, first selecting "18 5" using MAX() and then joining again to get the LEVEL corresponding to (18, 5) -- only, here there are *two* levels that would match that. Of course you could use another MAX.

```
SELECT A1.AGE, MAX(A2.LEVEL) FROM
  ( SELECT AGE, MAX(C) AS M FROM ( the query above ) AS A0 GROUP BY AGE ) AS A1
  JOIN
  ( SELECT AGE, MAX(C) AS M FROM ( the query above ) AS A0 GROUP BY AGE ) AS A2
ON (A1.AGE = A2.AGE AND A1.M = A2.M)
```

Or you could use a hack to limit the number of subqueries and self-joins:

```
SELECT AGE, SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(C, 5, '0'), ':', LEVEL), ':', -1)) AS LEVEL FROM (
    SELECT AGE, LEVEL, COUNT(*) AS C FROM STUDENT GROUP BY AGE, LEVEL
) AS INT GROUP BY AGE
```

That complex expression will first concatenate the numbers and the level in a single string, so that "1 FR" and "15 SR" become "00001:FR" and "00015:SR", that allows comparing in lexicographical order. Then MAX will extract the maximum in alphabetical order, which now is also the same as the numerical order, using the LEVEL when the numbers are equal. So you will now get

```
18   00005:XX
```

and finally SUBSTRING_INDEX will take the last element of the string, colon-separated, so the desired "XX" value.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation, really helpful, and solves my problem perfectly.